# How to read HBase table as a pyspark dataframe?

Tags: pyspark, hbase

Is it possible to read in Hbase tables directly as Pyspark Dataframes without using Hive or Phoenix or the spark-Hbase connector provided by Hortonworks?

I'm comparatively new to Hbase and couldn't find a direct Python example to convert Hbase tables into Pyspark dataframes. Most of the examples I saw were either in Scala or Java.

Answer (score 0):

You may connect to HBase via Phoenix. The sample code can be:
`df=sqlContext.read.format('jdbc').options(driver="org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver",url='jdbc:phoenix:url:port:/hbase-unsecure',dbtable='table_name').load()`

You may need to get spark phoenix connector jars: `phoenix-spark-4.7.0-HBase-1.1.jar` and `phoenix-4.7.0-HBase-1.1-client.jar`. Thanks